# Auto-Enhance Multiple Photos In Gallery?

Tags: camera, photos, auto-correct, editing

Is there a way to auto-enhance multiple selected photos without picking one by one which supposedly takes more time since it returns me to start of photos list and I have to navigate and find last photo I shot and once again navigate to "Auto-Enchance" option.

If there's only app that can accomplish that, it is fine, I would like to know which one is it.

**Andorid 2.3.5**
**HTC Desire S**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a fairly new app called [Perfectly Clear](http://www.athentech.com/android.html) which allows you to select multiple images and apply corrections to all of them at once in batch. You could also set a preset and apply the enhancements the same way for all images. Fair warning, for the more advanced features they have in-app purchases.

Comment: Thanks, but is this the only app currently capable of doing this?

Answer (score 3):

if you really do that often, compile/install image magic and use a script.  https://github.com/lilac/Android-ImageMagick

you will dread the though of going back to the lame algo in those apps.

Comment: I am UNrooted with stock 2.3.5 and suppose this is for advanced Android users.

What did you mean by lame algo? Does Image Magick replace camera Auto-Enchance effect in camera's editor?

Comment: you can compile and install your own APKs on non-rooted phones. or if you trust the link i sent, you can use the APKs ready from there. People usually mix up installing APKs with root-only or pirate apps. this is nonsense. installing apks is easy, but out of the scope here. The algo comment is just an allusion to the code quality and age in image magick. you don't get that quality/speed with 2.99 apps.